# What would the correct German lyrics of „Soft Kitty” in The Big Bang Theory be?

Tags: translation

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=0PIbjkGj67Y

It sounds like this:

> Weiches Kätzchen, warmes Kätzchen,
>   das nie und nimmer möht,
>   liebes Kätzchen, müdes Kätzchen,
>   schnörrt, schnörrt, schnörrt.

They obviously took some liberties with the German language. „Schnörrt” should obviously be „schnurrt”. *Möht* is nonsense, isn’t it? If so, what would a better line and couplet be?

For reference, the English lyrics are:

> Soft kitty, warm kitty
>   Little ball of fur
>   Happy kitty, sleepy kitty
>   Purr, purr, purr

Comment: *schnurrt* - *murrt*?

Comment: According to Google Translate, though I doubt it is entirely accurate: Weiche Kitty warme Kitty
Kleiner Fellball
Happy Kitty, schläfrige Kitty
Schnurren, schnurren, schnurren

Comment: @MatthewAshman Welcome to GermanSE! There's no need to rely on Google Translate here. The translation is wrong in *Kitty* (correct  would be *Kätzchen*) and *schnurren* (in this context we need the *Inflektiv*: *schnurr*). But still it doesn't rhyme.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, why does the word schnurr even exist? The word purr is based on the actual sound, so shouldn't it make sense in any language? Cats make a purring sound, not a schnurr sound.

Answer (score 9):

Hubert's answer is fine, but I would like to add that the German synchronization uses another song.

Every time someone sings "Soft Kitty" it's in [German a variation](https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/de/wiki/Katzentanzlied) of "Der Katzentatzentanz" by Fredrik Vahle, called "Das Katzentanzlied" in the show.

Lyrics

> Guck die Katze tanzt für sich allein,
>
> tanzt auf einem Bein.
>
> Kam ein Kater zu dem Kätzchen ...
>
> pa pa pa.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHi3hGT1_s8

Original song
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsvz0ZDMBUk

**EDIT**

I tried to look up the script of this episode, but couldn't find anything official. But there are quite a few transcripts made by fans. [One says Amy sings](https://bigbangtrans.wordpress.com/series-10-episode-20-the-recollection-dissipation/)

> Weiches Kätzchen, warmes Kätzchen,
>
> das nie und nimmer murrt.
>
> Liebes Kätzchen, müdes Kätzchen,
>
> schnurrt, schnurrt, schnurrt.

When thinking about how words like murderer, Murphy or murmur are pronounced in English it's quite possible Amy wanted to sing "murrt" (to grumble/murmur in English).

As DavidVogt suggested in the comments it's also logical, because murrt rhymes with schnurrt and schnurrt is definitely the last part of the song

Answer (score 6):

You are right. Amy is singing almost exactly what you wrote. The 3<sup>rd</sup> word in fact is *"w**o**rmes",* (with *o*) but its clear, that it should be *"w**a**rmes"* (with *a*). Also she is singing *Kätzen* instead of *Kätz**ch**en* all four times. But bravo: She did sing *müdes* correctly (I was expecting *u* instead of *ü,* a mistake almost every English native speaker makes, but Amy didn't.)

Now for the nonsense words. Neither *"möht"* nor *"schnörrt"* are German words. Similar words are:

- *muht*
  A form of *muhen* (to moo), but this is the verb to the sound a cow makes. The sound itself is *"muh".*
  When a cat makes a sound the verb is *miauen* (to meow) the sound is *"miau".* If this verb was used instead of *möht* it's form should have been *"miaut"* But this makes no sense here. A cat that never meows makes no sense. Btw: mi-aut has two syllables, so it wouldn't fit into the rhythm of the song.
- *schnurrt*
  This is a form of *"schnurren"* (to purr), which is another sound that cats can make. But when you use it like it is usd in this poem, you use only the stem of the verb, which is *"schnurr".* So the last line should de:

  > schnurr, schnurr, schnurr

I think the 2<sup>nd</sup> line only was chosen as it is because it sounds german and rhymes with the last line.

Some possible translations of *"happy"* (1<sup>st</sup> word in line 3) are:

- **glücklich** (happy, lucky, fortunate, contented, ...)
- **fröhlich** (festive, cheerful, gleeful, jolly, happy, gay, ...)
- **zufrieden** (happy, pleased, satisfied, content, ...)
- **froh** (glad, pleased, happy, cheery, ...)

But *lieb* (dear, good, nice, beloved) is not a good translation of *"happy"*

The correct translation is:

> Weiches Kätzchen, warmes Kätzchen,
>   kleiner Fellball,
>   glückliches Kätzchen, müdes Kätzchen,
>   schnurr, schnurr, schnurr

An alternative translation of the 2<sup>nd</sup> line is:

> kleiner Ball aus Fell

Comment: Das sollte doch wohl "murrt - schnurrt" sein.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Wenn es sich um ein polyglottes Kätzchen handelt, dann muht es vielleicht gelegentlich.

Answer (score 2):

Really, it's just mispronounced! It's either "das nie und nimmer mürrt" or "murrt".  Americans often put in Umlauts where they don't belong, and don't use them where they do!  But the point is humor, and Amy's mispronunciation is funny, too. Someone DID translate it adequately, however, if not absolutely literally!

Comment: Oh, for those who are interested, "murren" means "to grumble", so the 2nd line is "that never ever grumbles"!

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. What is the adequate translation you refer to? Can you please link and quote it? And please include the base verb form into your answer - answers should be understood without reading comment.s